# How to connect Angular2 with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, angular2-forms

I need little help for connect my front end angular2 with MongoDB
I have created a form crud and need connect with database MongoDB
Any Idea?

Comment: Take a look at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect Angular2 directly to MongoDB you need to use NodeJs also. There is a course on Udemy which is called Angular2 & Node - The Prectical Guide MEAN Stack. It may help you.

Comment: Hi MrSecret! 
Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect MongoDB with Angular Application using NodeJs and Express .
You'll need to set up a server with which you'll have to configure your port , etc .
Later you can coonect to your MongoDb either using Mongoose or MongoJs .